# Accessing a FormGroup inside a sub component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to access a form component inside another from another component. The structure is like this:

```
ComponentA ------------------- ComponentB
SubComponentA (This is where the form comes)
```

So from my ComponentB I'm trying to accessing to SubComponentA doing a `@ViewChild(ComponentA, {static: false}) componentA: ComponentA` and then get it from a method inside ComponentB like this `componentA.formGroup.reset(//data)` but it returns undefined. How can I get this formgroup inside SubComponentA? Thanks in advance

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-between-components (I don't get it worked, first time using it but the structure it's what I meant

EDIT: Calling the form via the selector it renders the form but what I can't get now is passing data to it.

Comment: use a shared service to create your form group.

Comment: Are ComponentA and ComponentB sharing the same formGroup? If so, you could inject the FormGroup into the constructor or you could pass it as an Input binding.

It would be helpful if you provided more code or a stackblitz.

Comment: who is undefined componentA or formGroup? put console.log(this.componentA) before your reset call and see what is shown in your browser console.

Comment: it's returning undefined the componentA call. I'm trying to make a stackblitz

Comment: StackBlitz added

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure than your component fully initialized a child's component view.

You should run method from children's components in `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook
not in `ngOnInit()`.

Documentation about [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)

In Angular 8 we can use properties or methods from a child's component in `ngOnInit()` when we define `static` as true.

For example:

```
@ViewChild( SubComponentAComponent, {static: true}) subcomponenta: SubComponentAComponent;
```

Comment: Do you mean calling the child method ngAfterViewInit() from the form or from the component that I'm trying to call it?

Comment: In the parent component, where you use child component

Comment: I tried this with no luck, another detail that I missed earlier is that calling the form via the selector it renders fine the form but what I can't get the reference to pass data to it